# Ruby on Rails - Display Name for enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have a Rails project in which I have an enum defined as follows on one of the model objects

`enum status : {unknown_status: 0, eligible_status: 1, certified_status:2}`

Is there a way to map each value to a displayable name... Something like this?

`enum status : {unknown_status("Status Unknown"): 0, eligible_status("Full Eligibility"): 1, certified_status("Full Certified"):2}`

Comment: Personally, I think the better solution for this is to use internationalization. Use the status as a key and you are done, it's a good practice not to put strings on the model.

Comment: I already have internationalization in place. However, I need the displayable name to show up in the Rails Admin interface. On other parts of the UI which I have developed myself, I am able to use internationalization to display the name. But I can't figure out how to get internationalization to show up on the Rails admin tool

Comment: Ok, then that's a different question. You should include that on your question. What admin tool are you using? where are you trying to show those names? I'm there are options but your question is not complete.

Comment: I'm using Rails Admin (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). I'm trying to show those names when adding/editing a new Physician (One of my model objects). On my Physician model, I have a property called status which is the enum I mentioned above in the question

Answer (score 0):

**If you declare your enum this way:**

```
enum status: [:unknown_status, :eligible_status, :certified_status]
```

Probably your Admin Interface will take the name of the symbol and not just the number.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html